# how do i replace multiple parameter value with a new value in urlparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, urlparse

I have multiple links

```
www.example.com/abc?file=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&url=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
www.example.com/abc?google=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&fb=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

etc
Now i want to change these parameter value to "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" how can i do that? all parameters are different and in other requests they will change as well

Comment: You have tagged two contradictory Python versions. If the Python version is relevant to your question, tag that version. Tagging different versions is not adding any useful information to your question.

Comment: Can you publish the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: i just got the answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example:

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs


def replace_params_with_x(url):
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    params= parse_qs(parsed.query)
    modified_params={key : ["x" * len (val) for val in values] for key, values in params.items()}

    url_modified=url.split("?")[0]
    # i have params
    rplc = "&".join([ "%s=%s" % (key, val) for key, values in modified_params.items() for val in values ])
    if rplc:
        url_modified += "?" +rplc


    return url_modified

# example on a single url (applicable to any url)
url = 'www.example.com/abc?file=my_file&url=my_url'
print(replace_params_with_x(url))
```

output:
`www.example.com/abc?&file=xxxxxxx&url=xxxxxx`